# Why in C# it is not important to know when the generation 1 was collected by GC while implementing the GCNotification?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, implementations

Why in C# it is not important to know when the generation 1 was collected by GC while implementing the `GCNotification`?

While reading the **CLR via C#** book I met the following excerpt:

> The GCNotification class shown below raises an event whenever a generation 0 or generation 2 collection occurs. With these events, you could have the computer beep whenever a collection occurs or you calculate how much time passes between collections, how much memory is allocated between collections, and more. With this class, you could easily instrument your application to get a better
>   understanding of how your application uses memory.

```
public static class GCNotification {
 private static Action < Int32 > s_gcDone = null; // The event's field
 public static event Action < Int32 > GCDone {
  add {
   // If there were no registered delegates before, start reporting notifications now
   if (s_gcDone == null) {
    new GenObject(0);
    new GenObject(2);
   }
   s_gcDone += value;
  }
  remove {
   s_gcDone -= value;
  }
 }

 private sealed class GenObject {
  private Int32 m_generation;
  public GenObject(Int32 generation) {
   m_generation = generation;
  }
  ~GenObject() { // This is the Finalize method
   // If this object is in the generation we want (or higher),
   // notify the delegates that a GC just completed
   if (GC.GetGeneration(this) >= m_generation) {
    Action < Int32 > temp = Volatile.Read(ref s_gcDone);
    if (temp != null) temp(m_generation);
   }
   // Keep reporting notifications if there is at least one delegated registered,
   // the AppDomain isn't unloading, and the process isn’t shutting down
   if ((s_gcDone != null) &&
    !AppDomain.CurrentDomain.IsFinalizingForUnload() &&
    !Environment.HasShutdownStarted) {
    // For Gen 0, create a new object; for Gen 2, resurrect the object
    // & let the GC call Finalize again the next time Gen 2 is GC'd
    if (m_generation == 0) new GenObject(0);
    else GC.ReRegisterForFinalize(this);
   } else {
    /* Let the objects go away */ }
  }
 }
}
```

When the generation 1 collection occurs the listeners will be passed 0 instead of 1 due to this line:

`if (temp != null) temp(m_generation);`

(since `m_generation` is never 1 in this example, but only 0 and 2).

Why did not we add a `new GenObject(1);`? Is it because we would have the listeners being called twice then (one for 0 and one for 1 when the generation  1 is collected)? In such a case, why are not they called twice due to the `new GenObject(2);` (one for 0 and one for 2 when the generation 2 is collected)?

Maybe the author just missed the `new GenObject(1);` accidentally, not intentionally?

Comment: Did you try to ask Jeffrey Richter, the author of that book? Googling for "Jeffrey Richter Microsoft" will find you quickly some contact paths.

Comment: Why questions often remains unanswered because the person making the original statement isn't represented here and all we can do is second-guess the OP. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? This being a QA site ... what is the Q?

Comment: It is impossible to know the authors intentions, but a guess is that gen 1 collections are not considered interesting. As I undestand it, the primary purpose of gen 1 is to catch short-lived objects that just happened to be alive when the GC occured. So it is similar to a gen 0 collection from a performance point of view.

Comment: @DocBrown, good point. Thank you.

Comment: @DocBrown, should I remove the question?

Comment: @DocBrown, ok. I wrote to Jeffrey Richter and linked the question in the message.